# How to start a ros node

Tags: ros, node, rosrun, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I start a ros node from the terminal? For example I'm looking to start the node `/camera/camera_nodelet_manager` but I have no idea how? Do I use rosrun?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198279/how-to-start-a-ros-node/) by [Giza](https://answers.ros.org/users/19792/giza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-11-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can either use rosrun or manually execute the binary/script. In the first case, run:

```
rosrun <package_name> <executable_name>
```

In the second case look up the executable name (if you're using catking, it's usually in

```
<catkin_workspace>/devel/lib/<executable_name>
```

**EDIT**

I see what you want to do now! If you want the nodelet manager (that's the node you're looking for), then you should look at manager.launch.xml in rgbd_launch. In particular the lines that you're interested in are:

```
<!-- Nodelet manager -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="$(arg name)" args="manager"
        output="screen" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)">
     <param name="num_worker_threads" value="$(arg num_worker_threads)" />
  </node>
```

where the name is set in the calling launch file (openni.launch, https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_launch/blob/hydro-devel/launch/openni.launch).

Just remember that all roslaunch does is to call processes, so if roslaunch can do it then you can do it as well at the command line! For example if you want to run the nodelet above, just type:

```
>> rosrun nodelet nodelet manager _num_worker_threads:=4
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2014-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Giza](https://answers.ros.org/users/19792/giza/) on 2014-11-26**:
seems like the only way I can run `/camera/camera_nodelet_manager` is to launch `openni.launch`

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2014-11-27**:
To run openni for my Kinect, I have been using [openni_launch](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch):

```
$ roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
$ rosrun rviz rviz  #In new terminal window
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new with ROS, so I feel your pain.  From what I understand, you must have roscore running.

$ roscore

In a new terminal window, use rosrun to start your node:

$ rosrun [*package_name*] [*node_name*]

I hope this helps...

---

Originally posted by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) with karma: 323 on 2014-11-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2